# c# HTTPListener encoding issue

Tags: c#, encoding, httplistener

I have a Java application sending HTTP requests to a C# application. The C# app uses HTTPListener to listen for requests and respond. On the Java side I'm encoding the URL using UTF-8.

When I send a \ character it gets encoded as %5C as expected but on the C# side it becomes a / character. The encoding for the request object is Windows-1252 which I think may be causing the problem. How do I set the default encoding to UTF-8?

Currently I'm doing this to convert the encoding:

```
        foreach (string key in request.QueryString.Keys)
        {
            if (key != null)
            {
                byte[] sourceBytes =request.ContentEncoding.GetBytes(request.QueryString[key]);
                string value = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(sourceBytes));
             }
        }
```

This handles the non ASCII characters I'm also sending but doesn't fix the slash problem. Examining request.QueryString[key] in the debugger shows that the / is already there.

Answer (score 4):

**short:**
you have to add `charset=utf-8` to content type in the response header.

header shoud look like this. 
Content-Type = "text/plain; charset=utf-8"

```
var text = "Hello World - Barkod Çözücü";
var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);

ctx.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;           // this doesnt work??
ctx.Response.ContentType = "text/plain; charset=utf-8"; //Fixxxx

ctx.Response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
ctx.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

**Long:**

response header of my http listener

```
//where is utf-8 ???  i need to put it somewhere here...!!!
Content-Length: 31
Content-Type: text/plain;    
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
```

i inspected  a web page that is capable to display utf-8 chars like turkish üğşİ

response header from that utf-8 website

```
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8    //so we have put it here like this.
content-length: 20270
content-encoding: gzip
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Encode each query string variable as UTF8:

```
byte[] utf8EncodedQueryBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
```